# How to get rid of \t and \n and then convert list into array

Tags: python

I've imported text and then printed it

```
with open('data1.txt') as f:
    x = f.readlines()[1:17]
    print(x)

x =  ['0.0000\t1.06E+05\n', '0.0831\t93240\n', '0.1465\t1.67E+05\n', '0.2587\t1.54E+05\n', '0.4828\t1.19E+05\n', '0.7448\t1.17E+05\n', '0.9817\t1.10E+05\n', '1.2563\t1.11E+05\n', '1.4926\t74388\n', '1.7299\t83291\n', '1.9915\t66435\n', '3.0011\t35407\n', '4.0109\t21125\n', '5.0090\t20450\n', '5.9943\t15798\n', '7.0028\t4785.2\n']
```

I then want to format this (without the `\t` and `\n`) into two separate columns in an array separated by `\t`

EDIT: SORRY SORRY SORRY put very little effort into question because I thought I was going to get zero responses, let me try again.

Data file is a .txt with a header at the top, followed by two columns of data separated by spaces.
Data that I need to extract is a 16*2 matrix of values
I'd like x to look like

```
x =  [[.0000  1.06E+05
       0.0831  93240
       0.1465  1.67E+05
       0.2587  1.54E+05
       0.4828  1.19E+05
       0.7448  1.17E+05
       0.9817  1.10E+05
       1.2563  1.11E+05
       1.4926  74388
       1.7299  83291
       1.9915  66435
       3.0011  35407
       4.0109  21125
       5.0090  20450
       5.9943  15798
       7.0028  4785.2]]
```

I did the [1:17] to skip the first line

```
with open('data1.txt') as f:
    x = f.readlines()[1:17]
    print(x)
```

I've tried to use a the delimiter function (incorrectly) and I've tried to load it in using a csv file (incorrectly)

```
length = 0
col1 = []
col2 = []
with open("data1.txt", 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
file.readline()
for line in csv_reader:
    col1=np.append(col1,float(line[0])*2
    col2=np.append(col2,np.sqrt(float(line[1])))
    length = length + 1
```

Comment: Why do you do `[1:17]`?

Comment: you can use `element.repalce('\\t', '')` to remove backslash t and use `element.strip()` to remove newline character

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the output you expect?

Comment: Your last sentence is very confusing, according to the title you don't want those `\t`.

Comment: Why not do a little experimentation before asking, and then show us what you've tried? Research "list comprehensions", for example, along with "string.replace"

Comment: @haifzhan You have a typo in your code, it should be `element.replace`, you have `element.repalce`. You can repost a comment with the corrected code.

Comment: @BryanOakley: or (safe as it is to assume OP is *highly* unfamiliar with Python) a `readline` loop with a `strip` and `replace`. I can think of at least a handful and possibly a dozen more options.

Comment: @usr2564301: I agree that there are many options, which is why I think this is a low quality question. There are a gazillion similar examples all of the internet of taking one list and converting it to another. The OP didn't even try.

Comment: sorry for incoherence of first post, thanks for feedback everyone

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is read in a tab delimited file. It might be worth looking into the `csv` library with the `delimiter='\t'` option.

If the input data (`text.txt`) looks like

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
7   8
```

You can read it in like:

```
import csv
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
     fread = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
     output = []
     for row in fread:
         output.append(row)
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l_rows = [x_i.strip().split('\t') for x_i in x]
[['0.0000', '1.06E+05'], ['0.0831', '93240'], ['0.1465', '1.67E+05']...]
```

`.strip` will take out the `\n` and then split the string into a list by the delimiter `\t`

```
>>> l_cols = list(map(list, zip(*l_rows)))
[['0.0000', '0.0831', '0.1465' ...], ['1.06E+05', '93240', '1.67E+05'...]]
```

Since you specified columns, this transposes the list using pure python